# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, gulp, requirejs, exec

I have simple question as it seems :)

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('.').pipe(exec('./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o rconfig.js'));
});
```

In this part of code I get next error:

> Command failed: ./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o rconfig.js
>
> '.' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.
>
> Details:
>
> ```
> killed: false
> code: 1
> signal: null
> cmd: ./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o rconfig.js
> ```

I think this is problem occurs cause I have gulp.src('.'), that incorrect according to this spec https://github.com/robrich/gulp-exec.

if I change gulp.src('.') to gulp.src('./') it will not fix too.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, don't use `gulp-exec`, use `exec`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('js', function (cb) {
    exec(
        './node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o rconfig.js',
        function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            cb(err);
        );
});
```

It says so in [their documentation](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-exec).